# Doctrine OneByOne's and Date

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I am using Symfony 2.7.1 and I seem to have a problem while using my News Entity. I am trying to use the published_at in my twig template.

I tried using `{{ news_item.published_at|date("m/d/Y") }}` but that seems to follow up by a fatal error:

```
Method "published_at" for object "AppBundle\Entity\News" does not exist in AppBundle:news:index.html.twig at line 7
```

Line 7:

```html
{{ news_item.published_at | date("m/d/Y") }}
```

I also get a 'Invalid entities' warning in the debug toolbar stating the following;

- AppBundle\Entity\Account

  - The association AppBundle\Entity\Account#articles refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\News#author which is not defined as association, but as field.
  - The association AppBundle\Entity\Account#articles refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\News#author which does not exist.

*These are my files*. I hope somebody can help me push me in the right direction:

<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/News.php</kbd>

```php
class News
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Account", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="published_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $published_at;
}
```

<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/Repositories/NewsRepository.php</kbd>

```php
class NewsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param $number
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function findLatest($number) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->orderBy('a.published_at', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($number)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/Account.php</kbd>

```php
class Account implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\News", mappedBy="author")
     */
    protected $articles;
}
```

Comment: Since you're using `private` properties you must provide `public` get/set methods in your entity and the template engine would be automatically able to access them. Did you added yours, or you simply left them out when you copied your code here?

Comment: @Artamiel: I left them out due to the length of my question (to minimize junk) but all the get and setters are public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity class needs getters (and setter).

```
class News
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="published_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $published_at;

    public function getPublished_at()
    {
        return $this->published_at;
    }
}
```

with this `{{ news_item.published_at }}` [will call](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) `News::getPublished_at`.

> (...) if not, and if foo is an object, check that getBar is a valid method; (...)

You can also directly get method in twig with `{{ news_item.getPublished_at() }}`

Comment: I do have the get and setters. I left them out this question due to the length of my question (to minimize junk). Your suggested Entity did not solve my problem, however. I used published_at instead of publishedat. It did solve my issue. Thank you.